# Replicating jQuery slideToggle without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anki

Since Anki doesn't support jQuery, how would I go about converting the jQuery on this particular document so that the same effects are produced in vanilla JS, or purely in CSS3 (specifically of the + button, and when clicking on list items)?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#show-pronunciation").on("click", function () {
        $(".pronunciation").slideToggle();
    });
    $("li").on("click", function () {
        $(this).find("dl").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Avenir, Futura, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.definitions dl {
    border-left: 2px solid #ff1919;
    padding-left: 5px;    
}

dt {
    font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
    margin-left: 1em;
}

.main {
    margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
    border: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /*padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;*/
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #FF4C4C;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.header {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
}

.content {
    margin: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
    border: transparent;
    border-top: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #FCE8E8;
}

.info {
    clear: both;
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
}

.grammatical-info {
    display: inline-block;
    border: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    background: deepskyblue;
    color: white;
}

.level {
    display: inline-block;
    border: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: right;
    padding: 3px;
    background: crimson;
    color: white;
}

.foreign-word {
    display: inline-block;
    border: transparent;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20pt;
}

.pronunciation {
    display: none;
    overflow: auto;
    border: transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 8pt;
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    bottom: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn {
    font-size: 20pt;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #999;
}

.btn:hover {
    color: #aaa;
}

.btn:active {
    color: #ccc;
}

#play-sound {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>2ndlang card type</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main">
  <div class="header">
   <button class="btn" id="show-pronunciation">+</button>
   <div class="foreign-word">
       制造
       <div class="pronunciation">
           zhì zào
       </div>
   </div>
   <button class="btn" id="play-sound"><img src="http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/elusive/svg/volume.svg" height="20px"/></button>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
      <span class="grammatical-info">动 verb</span>
      <span class="level">三</span>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="content">
   
   <div class="definitions">
    <ol>
     <li>
         manufacture
         <dl>
             <dt>中国制造</dt>
             <dd>Made in China</dd>
         </dl>
     </li>
     <li>
         create
         <dl>
             <dt>制造假象</dt>
             <dd>put up a false front</dd>
             <dt>制造紧张局势</dt>
             <dd>create tension</dd>
             <dt>制造麻烦</dt>
             <dd>make trouble</dd>
         </dl>
     </li>
    </ol>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use css transitions for that. E.g:

```
.pronunciation, li dl {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .3s linear;
}
.hidden {
  height: 0!important;
}
```

Take a look at the code below (same logic as yours, but converted to vanilla Javascript and CSS3):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var show = document.getElementById('show-pronunciation');
  var pron = document.querySelector('.pronunciation');
  
  pron.style.height = pron.clientHeight + 'px';
  pron.classList.add('hidden');  
  show.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    pron.classList.toggle('hidden');
  });
  
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('li'), function(el, i) {
    var dl = el.querySelector('dl');
    dl.style.height = dl.clientHeight + 'px';
    
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      dl.classList.toggle('hidden');
    });
  });  
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Avenir, Futura, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
.definitions dl {
  border-left: 2px solid #ff1919;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
dt {
  font-weight: bold;
}
dd {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.main {
  margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
  border: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /*padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;*/
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #FF4C4C;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.header {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}
.content {
  margin: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
  border: transparent;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #FCE8E8;
}
.info {
  clear: both;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}
.grammatical-info {
  display: inline-block;
  border: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
  background: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
}
.level {
  display: inline-block;
  border: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: right;
  padding: 3px;
  background: crimson;
  color: white;
}
.foreign-word {
  display: inline-block;
  border: transparent;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
.pronunciation {
  overflow: auto;
  border: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 8pt;
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  bottom: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn {
  font-size: 20pt;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #999;
}
.btn:hover {
  color: #aaa;
}
.btn:active {
  color: #ccc;
}
#play-sound {
  float: right;
}

.pronunciation, li dl {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .3s linear;
}
.hidden {
  height: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    <button class="btn" id="show-pronunciation">+</button>
    <div class="foreign-word">
      制造
      <div class="pronunciation">
        zhì zào
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn" id="play-sound">
      <img src="http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/elusive/svg/volume.svg" height="20px" />
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <span class="grammatical-info">动 verb</span>
    <span class="level">三</span>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="content">

    <div class="definitions">
      <ol>
        <li>
          manufacture
          <dl>
            <dt>中国制造</dt>
            <dd>Made in China</dd>
          </dl>
        </li>
        <li>
          create
          <dl>
            <dt>制造假象</dt>
            <dd>put up a false front</dd>
            <dt>制造紧张局势</dt>
            <dd>create tension</dd>
            <dt>制造麻烦</dt>
            <dd>make trouble</dd>
          </dl>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! One more thing, the animation for revealing the pronunciation is a bit rough, and the gap between list items is a bit large... any ways to fix those?

Comment: You can add a CSS class for each *togglable* element, and then you can do something like: `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.togglable'), function (el, i) { el.style.height = el.clientHeight + 'px'; });`, Doing that, the animations will look smoother.